# How to send a Javascript/Ajax variable to a php page using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
function runGetIperfSpeedAjax(speedVar, actualIp) {
    var xmlhttp = getAjaxObject();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            processIperfRequest(xmlhttp.responseText, speedVar);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'lib/getIperfSpeed.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function processIperfRequest(response, speedVar) {
    alert("proccess");
    document.getElementById(speedVar).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('displaySpeedTest').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('displaySpeedTest').innerHTML = response;
}
```

`getAjaxObject()` is not included as it is just standard. I am making an onclick JavaScript call that calls `runGetIperfSpeedAjax`. This all works properly if I hard set the IP in "lib/getIperfSpeed.php". But I cannot seem to pass the `actualIp` to "lib/getIperfSpeed.php". I tried `'lib/getIperfSpeed.php'+actualIp` to attempt to pass it and access it through post.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: why not trying jquery-Ajax,much easier

Comment: Please format your code properly when you post a question, it makes it easier to read and to understand (all the white space on the left hand side was completely unnecessary). Also please show us how you are trying to access the value. In the code you posted you are not even trying to send any data to the server, so obviously you cannot access it on the server side.

Comment: Do you want to use GET or POST? Maybe http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp can help you

Comment: @Oriol w3schools is a terrible resource. MDN describes the difference much bettter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass the ip as a GET value you have to add the GET key

```
function runGetIperfSpeedAjax(speedVar, actualIp) {
    var xmlhttp = getAjaxObject();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            processIperfRequest(xmlhttp.responseText, speedVar);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'lib/getIperfSpeed.php?ip='+actualIp, true);
    // missing in your code '&ip='+actualIp
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function processIperfRequest(response, speedVar) {
    alert("proccess");
    document.getElementById(speedVar).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('displaySpeedTest').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('displaySpeedTest').innerHTML = response;
}
```

so in the `getIperfSpeed.php` you get the `actualIp` with `ip`

```
$_GET['ip']
```

if you need to pass the actualIp with POST you need to change the ajax into POST.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I tried accessing the page with &ip=1.1.1.1 tagged at the end of the URL and that does not even work.

Comment: you need to look inside 'getIperfSpeed.php' and check where the actualIp is taken from.

Comment: try to replace actualIp with ip

Comment: I realized you need to pass the FIRST variable to a URL with a question mark. Like this: `?ip=1.1.1.1`

It worked fine with that. Thank you!